# SPFX how to add a readonly field to a Content Type

Tags: spfx, spfx-extensions

I need to create a List with an asset package with spfx.
 The list must contains 10 Columns that can not be edited by users but will be modified by buttons added with an spfx extension.

How can I do this ? Do you know if there are documentation or tutorials ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I have found the solution, in an spfx asset deployment you can add the property ReadOnly="TRUE" for a custom Field  exemple : 
 <Field ID="{0c5c0c1d-5584-46d2-97ee-7b13e7d3bb9a}"
           Name="SPFxAmountRO"
           DisplayName="Amount read only"
           Type="Currency"
           Decimals="2"
           Min="0"           
           Required="FALSE"
           ReadOnly="TRUE"
           Group="SPFx Columns" />

Answer (score 1):

Firs of all, [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/provision-sp-assets-from-package) is sample that will guide you through the process of creating SPFX package with assets.

I am afraid that there is no way how to completely lock the field and change it through REST API. You create field that is hidden in new and edit forms. Unfortunately if the user add the field to a view and try to edit it in the data grid, it will be possible to modify value of the field.

```
<Field ID="{SOME-GUID}" Name="ColumnName" DisplayName="Column name" Type="Text" ShowInNewForm="FALSE ShowInEditForm="FALSE" />
```

Field reference https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/field-element-field

> Note that Hidden="TRUE" nor ReadOnly="TRUE" cannot be used.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there any other way to add ReadOnly Columns ?

Comment: In Fact I tried the ReadOnly and it works perfectly.